# Closed quark loops written as traces

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, trace

I'm working out the quark loop diagram. I draw it as follows:

[image]

where the greek letters are the lorentz and dirac indices for the gluon and quark respectively and the other letters are color indices.
For this diagram I've written:

$$i\Pi^{\mu\nu}=\int_{}^{}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}.[ig(t_a)_{ij}\gamma^\mu].[\frac{i[(\not\! k-\frac{\not{q}}{2})+m_1]}{(k-\frac{q}{2})^2-m_1+i\epsilon}\delta_{il}].[ig(t_b)_{kl}\gamma^\nu].[\frac{i[(\not\! k+\frac{\not{q}}{2})+m_2]}{(k+\frac{q}{2})^2-m_2+i\epsilon}\delta_{kj}]$$

My question is: I want to explicitely write the matrix multiplication (with the indices for each term inside the brackets []) in order to write the numerator as a trace, but I'm rather confused on how to get there and which indices I've to work out.

In short, why can I write the above as:

$$i\Pi^{\mu\nu}=g^2T_F\delta{ab}\int_{}^{}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{tr[\gamma^\mu.((\not\! k-\frac{\not{q}}{2})+m_1).\gamma^\nu.((\not\! k+\frac{\not{q}}{2})+m_2)]}{((k-\frac{q}{2})^2-m_1+i\epsilon).((k+\frac{q}{2})^2-m_2+i\epsilon)}$$

where $T_F$ is the Dynkin index in the fundamental representation I get after contracting the generators and deltas. My doubt is how can I get to write the trace as it is on the numerator.

Comment: The delta functions contract the indices on the generators...

Comment: Yes, I know; but my point is getting the gamma matrices and the momenta inside a trace in the numerator

Comment: You haven't written the indices in the gamma matrices (which are "Dirac" indices rather than Lorentz indices)

Comment: Try writing them on the gamma matrices and the slashed variables

Comment: You mean the dirac indices from each quark in the vertices, correct? I completely forgot about that I'll check that out. Meanwhile I edited my previous post to make myself more clear

Comment: Each gamma matrix is just that:a matrix, so it has two indices. The closed loop forms these indices into a closed chain or cycle which creates your trace

Comment: I'm having some trouble arriving to the trace. Considering the indices I wrote and the Feynman rules(e.g http://users.ictp.it/~smr2463/lect/Ellis-1.pdf , page 17), writing the propagator as some matrix S, I get: $\gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}S_{\delta\alpha}\gamma^\nu_{\rho\delta}S_{\beta\rho}$. Such ordering of indices does not give me the trace. Where was my mistake in the ordering? Thank you for answering, by the way!

Comment: It does form a trace if you just rewrite the order of multiplication (you can do this because you're referring to real numbers indexed by the elements of the matices). Start with one of the propagators

Comment: Oh my, I'm feeling pretty dumb right now as I've been working out these diagrams moving matrix elements around, but completely forgot to do the same here... Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: No worries - glad you sorted it out. I'll write our joint working figuring out the details into an answer and maybe you could select it once I'm done :-) congratulations on getting there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am writing up the work done by OP with the help of some minor comments from me so that it is a record of their progress towards arriving at the answer to the question.

OP's expression was missing the "Dirac indices" associated to the gamma matrices that enter the definition of the vertices and the propagators. OP introduces these and found that a product appears:
$$\gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu}S_{\delta \alpha}\gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \delta}S_{\beta \rho}$$
and was then doubtful this forms a trace. Upon reordering the product of numbers OP arrived at 
$$S_{\delta \alpha}\gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu}S_{\beta \rho}\gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \delta} = tr_{\gamma}\left[S_{1} \gamma^{\mu}S_{2}\gamma^{\nu}\right]$$
where $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are the two fermion propagators.

Answer (score 1):

Consider one of the terms coming from the expansion of the numerator,

$$\text{tr }\gamma^\mu\not k\gamma^\nu\not k=k_\alpha k_\beta\,\text{tr }\gamma^\mu\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\nu\gamma^\beta.$$

If you really wanted to write out the explicit matrix-element indices, this would be

$$k_\alpha k_\beta\,(\gamma^\mu)_{ab}(\gamma^\alpha)_{bc}(\gamma^\nu)_{cd}(\gamma^\beta)_{da},$$

summing over $a,b,c,d$=$1\dots 4$. (These indices are written so seldom that I'm not sure whether most people write them lower/lower like I did or perhaps upper/lower.)

But there is seldom any reason to think about these matrix-element indices. You just use trace identities like

$$\text{tr }\gamma^\mu\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\nu\gamma^\beta=4(\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}-\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\beta}+\eta^{\mu\beta}\eta^{\alpha\nu}).$$